# GKE very slow image pull after switching to artifact registry

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-artifact-registry

we have used GKE with the docker images pushed/pulled from/to eu.gcr.io in the past, and the initial image pull for a node did take 1-2 minutes in the past.

A few weeks ago we started switching over to the new google artifact registry.

Since then, the initial upgrades/deployments via helm often fail, due to operation timeouts.
Looking in the details, now the initial docker image pull takes 3-6 minutes (For the same docker image sizes)

The gke cluster is in the same location (europe-west6-a) as the artifact registry (europe-west6).

Any ideas on how to speedup the initial image pull in gke?

Comment: Can you try enabling Image streaming to see if that will improve the pull time ?
I assume the size of your images did not change right ?

Comment: @boredabdel Thanks for the suggestion, but this did not improve things

Comment: Did anything change since you switched from gcr to ar ? both cluster and registry are in the same region? You image size is the same ? you node config in your GKE cluster is the same ?

Comment: No, we did not change other parts of the system, only switched over to ar

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot this if it's the image pull is the issue or the helm application.

You may try to pull the image manually from the artifact registry by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#pulling), and see if the time of pulling is same (either in your local, in one of the nodes or create a test vm).

There is also a workaround that might help you with this issue, available in this [link](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/11415).

Lastly, you may want to check your nodes disk utilization if the IOPS are reaching its limits base on your node type.

Comment: Pulling the 4GB docker image takes about 3.5minutes, and then another 10-20 seconds to expand it, is this value "normal" or is this slow?

Comment: IOPS on the nodes are not a problem